# Seat Reservation 2D Array Applied to Methods

Tags: java, array

I have completed my lab assignment for class, but I'm still wondering if there's any ways I could better optimize my code. specifically my methods isSeatAvailable and reserveSeat.
Here is my problem: Write a program that displays, examines and manipulates a two dimensional array
representing plane seats for a plane with 12 rows and 4 seats per row.
Write methods for the following operations:

fillSeatsRandomly:Fills the array with random values in range from 0 to 1.
Zero represents an empty seat and one represents a reserved seat.

displaySeats: Displays all the seats in the plane row by row. Empty seat is
displayed as 0 and a reserved seat is displayed as X. Create vertical headings
for the row numbers from 1 to 12 on the left hand side and horizontal column
headings from A to D (for the 4 seats in the row).

isSeatAvailable: Receives an integer representing a row number and a character
representing a seat from A to D. This method tests if the specified seat is
available, otherwise it returns false. This method displays an error message
when the seat selection is invalid.

reserveSeat: Reserves a specified seat.
Receives two parameters: an integer representing a row number and a character
representing a seat number from A to D. This method displays an error message
when the seat is invalid.

seatsAvailInRow: counts and returns number of seats available in given row.
Receives an integer representing row number.

findRowWithTwoSeats: This method look for the closest row with two adjacent
available seats. If two adjacent seats are not available it returns 0.

countSeatsAvail: counts the number of all seats available in the plane and
returns that number.

countTakenSeats: counts the number of all seats reserved in the plane and
returns that number.

Here is my code:

```
public class ArraysLab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Plane p = new Plane();
        p.fillSeatsRandomly();
        p.displaySeats();
        if (p.isSeatAvailable(2, 'B')) {
            System.out.println("You have reserved seat: 2,B");
            p.reserveSeat(2, 'B');
            p.displaySeats();
        }
        System.out.println("Sorry, seat: 2,B is already taken");
        System.out.println("There is " + p.seatsAvailInRow(5)
                + " seat(s) available in row 5");
        System.out.println("Row " + p.findRowWithTwoSeats()
                + " has 2 adjacent seats");
        System.out.println("Seats available: " + p.countSeatsAvail());
        System.out.println("Seats taken: " + p.countTakenSeats());
    
    }//end of main

}//end of class ArraysLab

class Plane {

    int[][] seats = new int[12][4];

    public void fillSeatsRandomly() {//fills seats randomly
        for (int[] seats1 : seats) {
            for (int col = 0; col < seats1.length; col++) {
                seats1[col] = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
            }//end of nested for
        }//end of for
    }//end of fill seats randomly

    public void displaySeats() {//displays the seats
        System.out.print("\tA  \tB  \tC  \tD \n");
        for (int row = 0; row < seats.length; row++) {
            System.out.print(row + 1 + "");
            for (int seatNum = 0; seatNum < seats[row].length; seatNum++) {
                if (seats[row][seatNum] == 1) {
                    System.out.print("\tX  ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("\t0  ");
                }
            }//end of nested for
            System.out.println();
        }//end of for
    }//end of displaySeats

    public boolean isSeatAvailable(int row, char column) {  //checks if seat is 
        //available, returns true if it is and false if not
        int rowNum = row - 1;//row number of the seat chosen
        char colChar = column;//character of the seat chosen
        int colNum = 0;//char converted to int for ease of use
        switch (colChar) {
            case 'A':
                colNum = 0;
                break;
            case 'B':
                colNum = 1;
                break;
            case 'C':
                colNum = 2;
                break;
            case 'D':
                colNum = 3;
        }
        //end of switch
        return seats[rowNum][colNum] == 0;
    }//end of isSeatAvail

    public void reserveSeat(int row, char column) {//reserves a seat updates array
        int rowNum = row - 1;//Row number of seat chosen
        int colNum = 0;//Column number of seat chosen
        char seatSelect = column;//Character of column chosen
        switch (seatSelect) {
            case 'A':
                colNum = 0;
                break;
            case 'B':
                colNum = 1;
                break;
            case 'C':
                colNum = 2;
                break;
            case 'D':
                colNum = 3;
        }//end of switch
        seats[rowNum][colNum] = 1;
    } //end of reserveSeat

    public int seatsAvailInRow(int row) {//checks how many seats are available 
        //in a row determined returns int value
        int rowNum = row - 1;
        int rowSum = 0;
        int avail;
        for (int[] plane1 : seats) {
            rowSum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < plane1.length; j++) {
                rowSum += seats[rowNum][j];
            } //end of nested for
        } //end of for
        avail = 4 - rowSum;
        return avail;//returns number of seats available
    }//end of seatsAvailInRow

    public int findRowWithTwoSeats() {//finds the closest row that has 
        //2 adjacent seats, returns row num, or 0 if none
        for (int i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < seats[i].length; j++) {
                if (seats[i][0] + seats[i][1] == 0 || seats[i][1]
                        + seats[i][2] == 0
                        || seats[i][2] + seats[i][3] == 0) {
                    return i + 1;//returns row num with adjacent seats
                }//end of if
            } //end of nested for
        } //end of for
        return 0;//returns 0 if there is no adjacent seats
    }//end of findRowWithTwoSeats

    public int countSeatsAvail() {//counts how many seats are available on the
        //plane, returns int value
        int count = 0;//used to keep track of how many seats are available
        for (int[] plane1 : seats) {
            for (int j = 0; j < plane1.length; j++) {
                if (plane1[j] == 0) {
                    count++;
                } //end of if
            } //end of nested for
        } //end of for
        return count;//returns the number of seats available
    }//end of countSeatsAvail

    public int countTakenSeats() {//counts number of seats taken on the plane, 
        //returns int value
        int count = 0;//used to keep track of how many seats are taken
        for (int[] plane1 : seats) {
            for (int j = 0; j < plane1.length; j++) {
                if (plane1[j] == 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            } //end of nested for
        } //end of for
        return count;//returns number of seats taken
    }//end of countTakenSeats
}//end of class plane
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can improve your code in multiple ways:

1. I believe you are using at least Java 8 version, so consider using **Stream API** for iteration. (please take example from enum static block)
2. **Remove duplicate code** or your code. Extract duplicate code in another private method. Like : `isSeatAvailable` and `reserveSeat` uses same switch code. And `countSeatsAvail` and `countTakenSeats` use almost same logic only one condition is different. (Added updated code below, where I have used Lambda to avoid code duplication)
3. **Method names should have consistency** like `countSeatsAvail` and `countTakenSeats` should be like `countTakenSeats` and `countAvailSeats`. (updated code with change is added, these method are not needed any more)
4. `Avoid using abbreviations for names` like Available to Avail. Until unless it's well-known abbreviation or it makes method too long.
5. `Avoid unnecessary variable creation` like in `reserveSeat` and `isSeatAvailabe` assign column to seatSelect and colChar variable. Even the names should have consistency as they indicate same value.
6. You can **avoid these switch cases condition** with enum. (updated code with change is added and you don't need it anymore)
7. **Method name should be clear to give the method details** as `seatsAvailInRow` should be rather `adjusentSeatsAvailableInRow`.
8. You can **avoid these unwanted comments** on each and every line. (ex endOfIf, endOfFor, endOfMethod etc.)

---

```
package test.file;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;

public class LatestClass {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Plane p = new Plane();
    p.fillSeatsRandomly();
    p.displaySeats();
    if (p.isSeatAvailable(2, 'B')) {
      System.out.println("You have reserved seat: 2,B");
      p.reserveSeat(2, 'B');
      p.displaySeats();
    }
    System.out.println("Sorry, seat: 2,B is already taken");
    System.out.println("There is " + p.seatsAvailInRow(5) + " seat(s) available in row 5");
    System.out.println("Row " + p.findRowWithTwoSeats() + " has 2 adjacent seats");
    System.out.println("Seats available: " + p.countSeats(panel -> panel == 0));
    System.out.println("Seats taken: " + p.countSeats(panel -> panel == 1));
  }
}
```

---

```
class Plane {

  int[][] seats = new int[12][4];

  public int countSeats(final IntPredicate condition) {//counts how many seats are available on the
    //plane, returns int value
    int count = 0;//used to keep track of how many seats are available
    for (final int[] plane1 : seats) {
      for (int j = 0; j < plane1.length; j++) {
        if (condition.test(plane1[j])) {
          count++;
        } //end of if
      } //end of nested for
    } //end of for
    return count;//returns the number of seats available
  }

  public void displaySeats() {//displays the seats
    System.out.print("\tA  \tB  \tC  \tD \n");
    for (int row = 0; row < seats.length; row++) {
      System.out.print(row + 1 + "");
      for (int seatNum = 0; seatNum < seats[row].length; seatNum++) {
        if (seats[row][seatNum] == 1) {
          System.out.print("\tX  ");
        } else {
          System.out.print("\t0  ");
        }
      } //end of nested for
      System.out.println();
    } //end of for
  }//end of displaySeats

  public void fillSeatsRandomly() {//fills seats randomly
    for (final int[] seats1 : seats) {
      for (int col = 0; col < seats1.length; col++) {
        seats1[col] = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
      } //end of nested for
    } //end of for
  }//end of fill seats randomly

  public int findRowWithTwoSeats() {//finds the closest row that has
    //2 adjacent seats, returns row num, or 0 if none
    for (int i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < seats[i].length; j++) {
        if (seats[i][0] + seats[i][1] == 0 || seats[i][1] + seats[i][2] == 0 || seats[i][2] + seats[i][3] == 0) {
          return i + 1;//returns row num with adjacent seats
        } //end of if
      } //end of nested for
    } //end of for
    return 0;//returns 0 if there is no adjacent seats
  }//end of findRowWithTwoSeats

  public boolean isSeatAvailable(final int row, final char colChar) { //checks if seat is
    //available, returns true if it is and false if not
    final int rowNum = row - 1;//row number of the seat chosen
    final int colNum = SeatColumn.getColumn(colChar);
    //end of switch
    return seats[rowNum][colNum] == 0;
  }//end of isSeatAvail

  public void reserveSeat(final int row, final char seatSelect) {//reserves a seat updates array
    final int rowNum = row - 1;//Row number of seat chosen
    final int colNum = SeatColumn.getColumn(seatSelect);
    seats[rowNum][colNum] = 1;
  } //end of reserveSeat

  public int seatsAvailInRow(final int row) {//checks how many seats are available
    //in a row determined returns int value
    final int rowNum = row - 1;
    int rowSum = 0;
    int avail;
    for (final int[] plane1 : seats) {
      rowSum = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < plane1.length; j++) {
        rowSum += seats[rowNum][j];
      } //end of nested for
    } //end of for
    avail = 4 - rowSum;
    return avail;//returns number of seats available
  }//end of seatsAvailInRow
}//end of class plane
```

---

```
enum SeatColumn {
  A(0), B(1), C(2), D(3);

  private static final Map<Character, Integer> seatColumnMapping = new HashMap<>();

  static {
    Arrays.stream(values()).forEach(v -> {
      seatColumnMapping.put(Character.valueOf(v.toString().charAt(0)), Integer.valueOf(v.column));
    });
  }

  private int column;

  SeatColumn(final int column) {
    this.column = column;
  }

  public static int getColumn(final char seat) {
    return seatColumnMapping.get(Character.valueOf(seat)).intValue();
  }

  public int getColumn() {
    return column;
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice answer. When you edit a question it is better not to edit the code.